# Calling pushViewController after a presentViewController does not work

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I am presenting my view controller like this -

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:self.thingContainerViewController animated:YES completion:nil]; //self.navigationController not nil here
```

This shows a UITableView. I want to push a VC on the navigation stack from here. But the self.navigationController is nil at this point. Any idea how to make this work?

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:otherContainer animated:YES]; //self.navigationController is nil at this point
```

Comment: have you solved above problem?? plz share with me

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap the view controller you are presenting in a navigation controller in order to be able to use the push and pop methods.

So for the first step:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.thingContainerViewController];
```

Then:

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If you do that, your code will work.

Comment: Thanks this this helps. However it need to configurate other navigation bar states, Anyway this will help you to move further.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3/Swift 4**

first of all you need to set navigation controller on which you want to present.After that do navigation process on your second view controller.

- **Example like that**

  ```
     let firstPresentVC = FirstVC(nibName:"FirstVC",bundle:nil)
     let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController:firstPresentVC)
     navVC.isNavigationBarHidden = true
     self.present(navVC, animated: true, completion:nil)
  ```

**Now You are on Present Stack With Navigation**

You can push after that

```
let secondPushVC = secondPushVC(nibName:"secondPushVC",bundle:nil)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondPushVC, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

UIViewController.navigationController means:

> The nearest ancestor in the view controller hierarchy that is a navigation controller.

on the other hand, `presentViewController` makes new view controller out of hierarchy, the new view controller has no navigation controller ancestor unless you assign one to it by `[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.thingContainerViewController]` as @Dima mensioned.

so, the solution is

```objectivec
UINavigationController *targetVCWithNavigationControllerAncestor = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.thingContainerViewController];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:targetVCWithNavigationControllerAncestor animated:YES completion:nil];
```

then you can push new view controller from `self.thingContainerViewController`